# how to get map fd and max extries if I have bpf_map object by using bpf_object__find_map_by_name(bpf_object,"hash_map"); ebpf

Tags: c, ebpf, xdp-bpf

So `struct bpf_map` member definition of `fd` and `max_entries` (which I need) are in source file (libbpf.c) and libbpf.h contains just declaration of ebpf map like `struct bpf_map map;` So I can't de-reference a pointer(which I have `struct bpf_map` of) to get fd and max extries which stored in struct within struct.

First So is there any way I can verify what returned from these two function are valids. is including libbpf.h enough for  including `libbpf_get_error` function

```
 struct bpf_object *obj=bpf_object__open(filename);
 if (libbpf_get_error(obj)) {
    printf("ERROR: opening BPF object file failed\n");
   }

 struct bpf_map *map=bpf_object__find_map_by_name(obj,"hash_map");    
 if (libbpf_get_error(map)) {
    printf("ERROR: finding map\n");
 }
```

And also moving on from here. How exactly can I get members of `struct bpf_map` and `struct bpf_map_def` if I have `struct bpf_map` object

Can anyone please tell me this?

I am interested in fd and max_entries;
If its not supported in ebpf libbpf then is there any value of syscall number in function

```
   long syscall(long number, ...);
```

and parameters lists that give me this info.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to dereference the pointers yourself, the structs are opaque on purpose. Just use the relevant functions [from libbpf](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/bpf/bpf-next.git/tree/tools/lib/bpf/libbpf.h?h=v5.19#n921):

```c
LIBBPF_API int bpf_map__fd(const struct bpf_map *map);
LIBBPF_API __u32 bpf_map__max_entries(const struct bpf_map *map);
```

> If its not supported in ebpf libbpf then is there any value of syscall number in function `syscall(...)`

There is, but this would only work to retrieve the information from the kernel, *after* the map has been created (which is admittedly what you want since you're looking for the fd anyway). The [`BPF_MAP_GET_FD_BY_ID` subcommand](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/bpf/bpf-next.git/tree/include/uapi/linux/bpf.h?h=v5.19#n380) for the `bpf()` syscall (`syscall(__NR_bpf, cmd, attr, size)`, see [`man bpf`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bpf.2.html)), would give you the relevant file descriptor, provided you know the map id, and the [`BPF_OBJ_GET_INFO_BY_FD` subcommand](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/bpf/bpf-next.git/tree/include/uapi/linux/bpf.h?h=v5.19#n389), with the [relevant arguments](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/bpf/bpf-next.git/tree/include/uapi/linux/bpf.h?h=v5.19#n1409) would allow you to find the maximum number of entries. But you would pretty much end up [reimplementing libbpf](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/bpf/bpf-next.git/tree/tools/lib/bpf/bpf.c?h=v5.19#n1086).